# Office365 Single-Sign out

Tags: c#, authentication, model-view-controller, single-sign-on, owin

I have implemented Single-Sign on in an existing C# Asp.Net MVC 4.5 application and therefore used Owin middleware and OpenIdConnectAuthentication.
The authentication and authorization works fine, but now I have following problem:

1. I sign in to my application by using AzureAD as identity provider
2. I sign in to Office365 in another browser tab
3. I sign out of my application - get redirected to the identity provider and also automatically sign out there
4. Office365 automatically signs out within the other tab

I do not have configured Single Sign out (so I didn't specified a Logout Url within the App Registration and neither in the configuration code), but I am still signed out of Office365. This is annoying for the customer, as he always uses Outlook365 within the browser.

How can I prevent Office365 from signing out the user automatically.

Here is a simplified code of my configuration of OpenIdConnect:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                    {
                        // ... my sign in logic ...
                        context.OwinContext.Response.Redirect(homeUrl);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                },
                AuthenticationType = OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
            });
```

And here is how I sign out of the application:

```
context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl }, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
```

Comment: I encounter this issue as well.

The difference scenario depends on the browser.

Microsoft Edge - Upon logging out on my application, it also logout my Teams, but office and OWA is still on.

Google Chrome - Upon logging out on my application, it also logout my teams and my OWA, but Office is still on.

anyone here can answer this? We really appreciate your help with this concern.